# How to find and determine the specific textbox which using same css class

Tags: jquery, html

How to I find and determine the specific textbox and set this value with specific value?

I have a table like this :

```
<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td><select class="code" id="data1_1" name="data1_1"></select></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="small1" id="data2_1" name="data2_1" value="" readonly="readonly"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="small1" id="data3_1" name="data3_1" value="" readonly="readonly"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="small2" id="data4_1" name="data4_1" value="" readonly="readonly"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="small1" id="data5_1" name="data5_1" value="" readonly="readonly"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my jQuery :

```
$("#customFields").on('change', '.code', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    id = $this.val();
    text = $this.find('option:selected').text();
    $this.closest("tr").find(".small1").val(id);
});
```

When I use `$this.closest("tr").find(".small1").val(id);` all my textbox will be filled with the same value.

How do I get a textbox first, second, third (different class) and fourth so I can fill it with different values ​​of the results of the process?

Comment: 3 of the inputs has the same class why can't you add different classes to them

Comment: Case close : http://jsfiddle.net/f4Hfc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `eq()` to select a particular element in the array using index.

```
var i=0;// i is the index to be selected.
$this.closest("tr").find(".small1").eq(i).val(id);// The first of the input element with class small1 is selected by eq(0).
```

Answer (score 0):

Get `id` of the element using `.attr()` because foe every **input** your id is different:

```
$('.small1').attr('id');
```

Comment: ID will be dinamic, like this `count += 1;` become `id="data2_'+count+'"`

Comment: Thats what you want right?You want to identify the element uniquely?

Comment: Yes...I want to set the value of some textbox in a row. The value of the fourth textbox will differ from each other, because I will do a query based on the combo box selected

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nth-child`, that way you can specify the first, second and third

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/